# IsEnabled not changing with CanExecute (Programmatic binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a piece of code that does localization and has logic to handle hyperlinks with commands. Right now I am creating the hyperlink and tying the command via the following code.

```
hyperlink.SetBinding(Hyperlink.CommandProperty, new Binding(description.CommandName));
```

This works, except it is not changing the `IsEnabled` property on the hyperlink as a normal binding. Does this only happen with a `CommandBinding`? If so, then how can I create one when I do not have the command yet?

Comment: `CanExecute` is tricky. Are you sure that its raising `CanExecuteChanged` correctly?

Comment: You may also call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` if `CanExecuteChanged` isn't practical.

Comment: Something is hitting the CanExecute, it just isnt updating the IsEnabled property, and calling InvalidateRequerySuggested does no good as that must be called. This is essentially creating the xaml behind the scenes and then should be letting the framework take over...

Comment: As @LucasTrzesniewski said I used this solution to get my `IsEnabled` property to get changed sample: `public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add    { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }`. HTH